# vtiger 6 blank (white) page on import

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, vtiger

When I try importing contacts and organizations into vtiger 6 I get a blank page with no PHP errors. Can anyone help.

I have tried PHP Error display on, checked all the folders and files to be uploaded properly and making Smarty folder read/writable.

In the index.php file I have added the error display and I get no errors as well.

Thanks

Comment: check here and looks like you are not using RC version https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/167157/vtiger-6-data-migration/p1

Comment: I am using the RC version.

Comment: I am reinstalling the Vtiger 6 from scratch. The new version is not the RC and I will post the outcome here.

Comment: Ok, and I have some real bad experience always with the importing feature on vtiger right from V 4.2 where I had to change code in the import module. Hope it works fine for you without having to change any code.

Comment: Fresh install did not work. The same problem exists. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I have set the error reporting and notices on and I get the followings----Standards: Declaration of Vtiger_LanguageExport::export_Dependencies() should be compatible with that of Vtiger_PackageExport::export_Dependencies() in /var/www/vhosts/terracad.com/gotiger.doubleview.org/vtlib/Vtiger/LanguageExport.php on line 16 Strict Standards: Declaration of Vtiger_LanguageImport::initImport() should be compatible with that of Vtiger_PackageImport::initImport() in /var/www/vhosts/terracad.com/gotiger.doubleview.org/vtlib/Vtiger/LanguageImport.php on line 16

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method Import_Utils_Helper::getSupportedFileExtensions() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/vhosts/terracad.com/gotiger.doubleview.org/modules/Vtiger/views/Import.php on line 84 Strict Standards: Non-static method Import_Utils_Helper::getSupportedFileEncoding() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/vhosts/terracad.com/gotiger.doubleview.org/modules/Vtiger/views/Import.php on line 85 Strict Standards: Non-static method Import_Utils_Help...

Comment: Now I have the error log from the server as this --- File does not exist: ...... libraries/bootstrap/css/images/wall1.jpg, referer: .... /libraries/bootstrap/css/jquery.bxslider.css [While it exists]

Comment: and [/....../libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('/var/www/vhosts...', '<?php /* Smarty...', Object(Vtiger_Viewer))\n#1 ..../libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(155): Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource()\n#2 ....../libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('modules/Setting...', NULL, NULL, NULL, true)\n#3 .... /includes/runtime/Viewer.php(177): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('modules/Setting...')\n#4 ]

Answer (score 1):

Try after enabling debugg . May be an issue with php max execution time. in vtiger 6 if there is morethan 250 records, it will be scheduled to import later. So enable your cron also . Not sure if its help you.

Comment: [2268] DEBUG VT - Exiting getActionid method ...
[2268] DEBUG VT - Exiting isPermitted method ...
[2268] DEBUG VT - Entering isPermittedCustomView(7,,Contacts) method....
[2268] DEBUG VT - Prepared sql query being executed : SELECT status, userid FROM vtiger_customview WHERE cvid=?
[2268] DEBUG VT - Prepared sql query parameters : [7]
[2268] DEBUG VT - Entering when status=0
[2268] DEBUG VT - Permission @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ : no

Comment: Lajeesh thank you for your reply. Import shows a blank page. So is the email function. The above is what I got. I could not also find Smarty_setup.php to add the debug (https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/DebugTechniques#Database). I could not also find any "Error"in the log otherwise.

Comment: I believe this given debug info is not related to import. I have tested in my vtiger 6 and its working fine. While importing where you get stuck(which screen) . If you need I will have try in your vtiger instance for free